# I wanna color a fa icon HTML

Tags: html, css

Suppose to have a fa icon:

//this code is not correct

```
  <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color:#FFFF00;"></i>
```

My purpose is to color the trophy itself and not the backgroud outside the trophy. Now the trophy it appears me black how can I change trophy color in yellow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Font awesome is a font - use the CSS color property to change the color, rather than background-color.

```
<i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #ffff00;"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the color property for fa icons.

```
<i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:yellow;"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

fa icon is a font. Please use color property for this.

```
<i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#357ebd;"></i>
```